# How to log into new EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

Trying to connect using CentOS7

I deployed a couple of EC2 instances using terraform and now and trying to log in.

```
aws2 ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --instance-id i-0788274a4861154d44 --availability-zone us-east-2 --instance-os-user ec2-user --ssh-public-key file:/aws_ssh/my_rsa_key.pub

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter SSHPublicKey, value: 42, valid range: 256-inf
```

I tried this command as well

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f my_rsa_key -b 1024
```

Still gives the same error.

I am new to this so as much help as you can give.

Comment: Can you able to login to the server via putty or any other client

Comment: @ManikandanRam   yes I can through the aws console

Comment: Im asking whether you can able to login to server via Putty..! Are you new to AWS..

Comment: @ManikandanRam yes very new

Comment: Try the below command and ping me

Answer (score 1):

Connect using this command.. You tried to connect the instance using the first command...

> aws ec2-instance-connect  send-ssh-public-key --region us-east-1  --instance-id  i-0989ec3292613a4f9  --availability-zone  us-east-1 --instance-os-user ec2-user --ssh-public-key file://mynew_key.pub

After authentication, the public key is made available to the instance through the instance metadata for 60 seconds. During this time, connect to the instance using the associated private key

> ssh  -i  mynew_key  ec2-user@ec2-34-204-200-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com

If for some reason you don’t connect within that 60-second window, you see the following error:

> ssh -i mynew_key ec2-user@ec2-34-204-200-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com
>    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: Still getting the same error: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter SSHPublicKey, value: 42, valid range: 256-inf

Comment: https://tech.smartling.com/getting-started-with-terraform-and-aws-ec2-first-steps-workshop-1-e38607f0fd4c   Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

send-ssh-public-key just support

1. Amazon Linux 2 (any version)
2. Ubuntu 16.04 or later

see this document: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why..? But the problem got fixed after making the following changes in the syntax..

file:/ by file:///

> aws2 ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --instance-id
>   i-0788274a4861154d44 --availability-zone us-east-2 --instance-os-user
>   ec2-user --ssh-public-key file:/aws_ssh/my_rsa_key.pub
>
> aws2 ec2-instance-connect send-ssh-public-key --instance-id
>   i-0788274a4861154d44 --availability-zone us-east-2 --instance-os-user
>   ec2-user --ssh-public-key file:///aws_ssh/my_rsa_key.pub

```
{
    "RequestId": "dd452b0f-89c3-4a01-82ea-c6a55934ec3f",
    "Success": true
}
```